# Text is starting from new line before completely utilising current line in textview Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

```
    android:id="@+id/message_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
    android:padding="@dimen/space_8"
    tools:text="Message" />
```

Please check the attached image, As you can see, after the word "give" there is enough space to accommodate "a" but got wrapped before reaching end margin

[image: Final output]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use different way of text break down so in this case you can use `breakStrategy` (in xml `android:breakStrategy=`)

you can try with different possible value to achieve your desired output

For more information

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#BREAK_STRATEGY_BALANCED

Comment: the suggestion you gave works, but unfortunately I have to support API level 21